# Query regarding notification on Android

Tags: android

I have the following requirement.

1> I have developed an Android mobile application & lets assume the user is currently on screen X.

2> If the user clicks on the HOME button of the mobile device , the mobile application goes to background & the user is currently on the HOME screen of the mobile device.

3> I want to show an icon of the my mobile application on the top of status bar at the extreme left (where the battery strength , clock , signal of the device) are shown , to inform the user that my mobile application is running on background. If the user clicks on the icon , he should be navigated to the screen X of the mobile application.

Actually , it should be such that whenever my mobile application is on background & the user is on the HOME screen of the mobile device, the icon of my application should be displayed on the status bar.

I have seen such an implementation but I am not sure how can I implement this type of notification.

Kindly provide your suggestions/sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,
CB

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I am aware of the Notification classes to be used but need the following clarification.                                                        i> I have 10 Activity screens & the user can go to the Home screen of the mobile device from any of the screens by clicking on the Home button of the device. My question is do I have to individually handle the notification at all the Activity screens ?

Comment: You will, but it doesn't have to be too onerous - you could (for example) extend `Activity` to handle the generic notification logic in onPause and then have each of your activities extend that instead of the Android provided `Activity` - it depends how generic you can make your notifications. Bear in mind, if you use this option, you will need to call `super.onPause` in each of your activities.

Comment: Of course - I meant you will need to call `super.onPause` in each activity's `onPause` method.